# Mulit select box Jquery 1.7 doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, selectedvalue, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have multi select box like below

```
    <select id="ccListSelect" name="ccListSelect" multiple="true" width="50">
    <option value="1">1111</option>
    <option value="2">2222</option>
    <option value="3">3333</option>
    </select>
```

Below jquery code (**1.7.2**) works in Chrome but not IE

```
    $.each($("#ccListSelect option:selected"), function(){            
        alert($(this).val());
        
    });
```

I've tried below also doesn't work in IE. Chrome is ok.

```
$("#ccListSelect").click(function() {
    var v=$(this).val();
      alert(v);
    });
```

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I tried to test your code with the IE 11 browser and it works fine on my side.

I also tested the code with other document modes like IE 10, IE 9, IE 8, IE 7, and IE 5. all worked fine.

Tested code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
      $.each($("#ccListSelect option:selected"), function(){            
        alert($(this).val());        
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <select id="ccListSelect" name="ccListSelect" multiple="true" width="50">
    <option value="1">1111</option>
    <option value="2">2222</option>
    <option value="3">3333</option>
 </select>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

If the issue persists then try to check the console for the error message. It can be possible that the issue caused by some other code. You can also try to run my above sample directly in the IE browser to check for the result. It may help you to narrow down the issue.